# Unity IAP - Get currency on the purchase price

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I'm experimenting with Unity IAP for Android and iOS, through the "IAP Button" script I connected a Text component that prints the price of the product, but I can't also print the currency, for example € or $. I also thought about writing a script that would determine the user's zone, but from the documentation I found the component:

```
product.metadata.localizedPriceString;
```

which should return the currency automatically. The problem is that I can't implement this method without running into null exception errors. Would anyone be able to give me an example of this working code? Thanks everyone for the help.

I also attach the line of code that should return the value, but nothing happens. (I specify that I have already created the product and tested the IAP which works without problems).

```
private string price_Symbol;
public Text priceSymbol;
IStoreController m_storeController;
Product product;
string productId;

private void Start()
{
    productId = "product_test";
    product = m_storeController.products.WithStoreSpecificID(productId);
    symbol();
}

public string symbol()
{
    price_Symbol = product.metadata.localizedPriceString;
    Debug.Log($"price_Symbol: {price_Symbol}");
    return price_Symbol;
    
}
```

The error I get is:

> `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

In the line: `m_storeController.products.WithStoreSpecificID(productId);`

Maybe something is missing in the "Product" declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you haven't initialised  m_storeController to anything.

I think what you want to do is create a class that extends the interface "IStoreListener". Note the following wont compile unless you also implement everything required by the IStoreListener interface.

```
using UnityEngine.Purchasing;

    public class myIAP :  MonoBehaviour ,IStoreListener
    {

       IStoreController m_storeController;


    public void OnInitialized (IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions)
    {
        this.m_storeController = controller;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the line `price_Symbol = product.metadata.localizedPriceString;` is written like that? According to [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.purchasing@4.10/api/UnityEngine.Purchasing.ProductMetadata.localizedPriceString.html) the `localizedPriceString` returns a `string`, but you're assigning the result directly to a `Text` component.

If the `Text priceSymbol` is correctly assigned in your inspector, then `price_Symbol.text = product.metadata.localizedPriceString;` should work as expected.

Comment: Forgive me, the code was not complete, I was first testing whether I received the symbol through a debug log, but the problem is upstream, I receive the error: "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"                    in the line: "product = m_storeController.products.WithStoreSpecificID(productId);"